# How to getExtra() after an intent of FileChooser?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this snippet :

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, FileChooserActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(activityIntent, 0);
String selectedFile = activityIntent.getStringExtra("SelectedFile");
```

When I get the extra from the `activityIntent`, I have an empty value for `selectedFile`.

How can I `getExtra()` **after** filechooser choosed the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss-understanding how `startActivityForResult` works.

To get the data for `SelectedFile` in your first `Acitvity` you should do this in `FileChooserActivity`:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("SelectedFile", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

then you will have a value in your first `Activity`.

**UPDATE:**

In your first `Activity` you should have `onActivityResult` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(data.getExtras().containsKey("SelectedFile"))
    {   
         String file = data.getStringExtra("SelectedFile");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have that in the 'FilechooserActivity' , the question is how to get the value of `selectedFile` ?

Comment: so in `Activity` : I have it like a value in selectedFile ?

Comment: I have my current `activity` and `fileChooserActivity`. I would like to get the vaue of selectedFile in current `activity` How?

Comment: add the method I added in the update in your current activity

Comment: I already have this in the filechooserActivity :`Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("SelectedFile", currentDir.getPath() + "/" + o.getName());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);`

Comment: the current activity is the activity where you run startActivityForResult and where onActivityResult should be. if this you already doing all those steps then you have a mistake some where.

Comment: look at my updated answer, I pasted there a code snippet of this method